# SQL Server delete trigger not capturing username (SUSER_SNAME)

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-interface, triggers

I am using web application to insert, update and delete records in a SQL Server table. The audit for this table is captured in another table when any insert, update, delete happens from GUI.

The insert, update is capturing the username correctly but the delete from GUi capture the SQL account not the web username, who deleted the records.

Please suggest a solution.

The trigger code for delete is as below:

```
-- DELETE
if exists (select 1 from deleted) and not exists (select 1 from inserted)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id varbinary(85)
    DECLARE @who varchar(50)

    SELECT @id = [Transaction SID]
    FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
    WHERE [Operation] = 'LOP_BEGIN_XACT'
      AND [Transaction ID] = (SELECT TOP 1 [Transaction ID]
                              FROM fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) 
                              WHERE Operation = 'LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
                                AND AllocUnitName like 'dbo.sampletable%'
                              ORDER BY [Transaction ID] DESC)

    SET @who = SUSER_SNAME(@id)

    INSERT sampletableAudit
       SELECT 
          'D' as Operation, Id, Type, @who, getdate()
       FROM 
          deleted
END
```

Comment: Unless you make your connection to sql with the web users name you aren't going to get it in sql. That will return the username of the user who made the connection to sql.

Comment: The confusing part is it captures the insert, update user (ad\XXXXX) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

On an active machine this query takes forever. Who knows what happens to this query if, and when, the transaction log is backed up. On my machine (which has a busy database) this has been running for 7 minutes with no results so I stopped it.

If you are running SQL Server 2008 and on you can get the same results using SQL Server Audit (with much, much less of an impact). Otherwise why can't you just use user_name?

Comment: SQL Server Audit cannot be setup due to some policy.